# Are Zinc–carbon batteries safe to use in my controllers?

Tags: controllers

I came across a site selling 60 Zinc–carbon batteries for around $10 including shipping.  They expire in 2014.

As I go through quite a few batteries in my gaming, I researched Zinc–carbon batteries and their use in wireless controllers.  On [their site](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wiisafety.jsp) Nintendo warns not to use them  with the Wii and inside of the XBOX 360 controller's battery chamber it reads that only Alkaline batteries should be used.

I've read user reports of Zinc-carbon batteries being safe for use with a few drawbacks.  Reduced battery life compared to Alkaline batteries and the 360 being unable to warn when the life of the battery is low.

Some say that the warnings are there to prevent liability if the batteries leak and damage the hardware.  Others say the warnings are there to enhance user experience as alkaline batteries last over four times longer.

[image: http://www.woot.com/Forums/viewpost.aspx?PostID=4755755&PageIndex=4&ReplyCount=332#post4756020]

Are Zinc–carbon batteries safe to use in my controllers?  What are the differences between them and other battery types?

Comment: remember to take them out when oyu are not gaming so that [*when* they leak](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5559/should-we-remove-batteries-from-electronic-devices-when-not-in-use/5560#5560) they don't destroy your controller

Comment: They only last 2 hours at most? Sounds like an environmental disaster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to power for expensive electronics, and potentially shoddy chemical storage units you're going to be holding in your hand, I tend to err on the side of caution.

Pretty much every controller vendor sells a rechargeable battery pack, which will last you far longer and be far safer for you than using cheap batteries off-spec.

The risk of it damaging your controller or leaking on you or your property is not worth the cost savings of using a battery that isn't rated for use in the device you're using it in.

Plus, think about how irritating changing the batteries in your controllers is, especially when you're trying to do something tricky or play online.  Now you're increasing the frequency of that annoyance.  It would be like buying 1/4th size toilet paper rolls... that dispense toilet paper potentially laced with battery acid.

So are they safe?  NO!

Comment: And to bring your analogy back to the safety issue, it would be like buying 1/4th size toilet paper rolls that may contain poison ivy.

Comment: Could not figure out how to finish that sentence.  Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: `So is it safe?`

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO!.jpg, also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14